# Cordova/CDVViewController.h file not found

Tags: xcode, cordova

**"Build"**, **"Archive"** was successful. The archive had also passed validation.

However when I try to **"Build for" => "Archiving"**, I hit the error **Cordova/CDVViewController.h file not found**.

I am experiencing this issue in version 2.4.0 of Cordova/Phonegap in Xcode 4.6

Most of the existing solutions given had already tried but failed.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also met this problem, and finally find out why.Did you create a new Configuration by duplicating "Release" Configuration and set "Archive"'s Build Configuration to the new Configuration? Don't do it,just keep Build Configuration for "Release".Then everything will be OK.

---

Or you should keep your project and the CordovaLib project for the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple configurations, but you have to add the same configurations to the CordovaLib sub-project. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35743530/758862).