# Cordova iOS - New Xcode Configuration / CDVViewController.h Not Found

Tags: xcode, cordova

I get a 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found build error when creating a new configuration for a Cordova project. I did try adding "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" to the project Header Search Paths as suggested in many forums, no luck.

I'm using:

- Cordova 3.4.1
- Xcode 7.2.1

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Cordova project
2. Add ios platform
3. Open Xcode project
4. Run project just to verify it builds and works
5. Go to project build settings and create a new configuration by duplicating "Debug", I called mine "DEV"
6. Edit the default scheme to use the new configuration for Run, Test, Profile, Debug, Release
7. Run the project again
8. Kaboom! - 'Codorva/CDVViewController.h' file not found

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It seems to be related to the configuration name. I deleted the original "Debug" configuration and renamed the "DEV" configuration back to "Debug" and it works. So for now I'm just going to keep the configurations named "Debug" and "Release".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem for a couple of weeks. Now I found the answer [here](https://cordovablogsblogs.wordpress.com/2015/12/29/cdvplugin-h-file-not-found-in-cordova-as-component-cleaver/)

If you want to add a new configuration by duplicating for example "Debug" to be able to change some build setting, you have to add the same configuration to the **CordovaLib** sub-project. You have to make sure that the **CordovaLib** sub-project has the same set of configurations as your main project. Otherwise the build folder for the Cordova Project is different than the build folder of the main project. Thus files like CDVViewController.h can not be found.

1. Select CordovaLib sub-project
2. Click on the project icon (above the Targets)
3. Select Info tab
4. Expand Configurations

Add the same set of configurations as in the main project:

1. Click + button
2. Select Duplicate "Release" Configuration or "Debug" Configuration, depending on your needs
3. Give the right name for configuration. Copy-paste it from main project settings.

Adding "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" to the project Header Search Paths only solves issues with archiving release builds.

Comment: Your suggestion makes perfect sense and worked great. 

For anyone else experiencing this, just make sure you clean the project too, or  you will continue to have the issue.

Comment: Thanks! The main idea of the answer is "make the same configuration types in a CordovaLib project as in a main project."

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turned out that something had gone wrong when adding the ios platform (I had a missing image file). I removed the platform with:

```
ionic platform rm ios
```

And then added it back with:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

If this doesn't work, make sure you have the latest Xcode (update using the app store), Cordova and Ionic installed.

```
npm uninstall -g cordova ionic
npm install -g cordova@latest ionic@latest
```

As you can see I am using Ionic with Cordova, if you are not, substitute 'ionic' with 'cordova' or leave it out in the command above.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include` was already in the *Header Search Paths* (using XCode 8). I then added to *User Header Search Paths* the specific path to `CordovaLib` folder, with `recursive` option enabled (for unexperienced XCode users like myself, select the project in the tree view (1st node) to see *"Build Settings"*!!)

But watch out for spaces! After a lot of missings it was safer to just drag the folder from a finder window, and it filled as `$(SRCROOT)/..` (cont.), which was not expected but did work..

Also in `XCode/Preferences/Locations/Custom Paths` I've added a *CORDOVALIB* name with the same folder as before, in the same manner (this time, the full path was used, without the `$(SRCROOT)` thing).

Took me quite some hours to figure all out...