# Error building ios with cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a problem when I build the ios platform with cordova. I have all the certificates for the app and device, but when I try to run in my ios device, doing ionic run ios, the console return this error:

```
Error: Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png
```

This path is written in config.xml file.

I tried to run it in xCode but the problem there was:

```
Cordova/CDVViewController.h not found
```

I read a lot of possible solutions but any works for me.

My xCode version is 7.3.1, the cordova version is 6.3.0 and the cordova ios version is 4.2.0.

Comment: Can you show some code examples of your `config.xml` and `index.html`? And also the exact error your getting on the command line?

Comment: Regarding the second problem, please refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39680894/3645375)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've had same error only with other image:

> Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png

This happened after upgrading to `Cordova 6.3.0` and I've solved it downgrading `Cordova`.

Quickfix for now:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@6.2.0
```

Comment: Note: for those who cannot change their `cordova` version (e.g. because of using a rented Mac), check out my answer. It works with `Cordova 6.3.0` as well.

Comment: Hi I have same error, I'm curious why using higher version of Cordova will cause this issue? Or if I want to use > Cordova 6.3.1, how do I do?

Comment: how on earth are you able to locate this solution?? anyway, it works for me. thanks.

Answer (score 60):

If you are missing the icon you can run the command

```
ionic resources --icon
```

This will generate all the icons with the pixels needed to run on any device.

To simulate on the device you first need to

```
ionic build ios
```

and then

```
ionic simulate ios
```

It is also a good practice to have xcode up to date.

If you are still getting the error you can paste this line

```
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"
```

on Build Settings > Header Search Paths.
Do not remove the similar line, just add it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't build ios because it show the same error. And now in the xCode instead of the CDVViewController error now I have CDVAppDelegate.h error.

Comment: Did you tried to paste the line I provided you in the header search path? I came across this problem a few days ago and that solved it.

Comment: Yes I did! And it resolve only one error and now I have the other error

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joseph Ocasio!

Comment: this does nothing for me

Answer (score 39):

**Update - 03-08-2017**

```
> ionic cordova resources
```

**Old CLI command:**

I had the same error, and after re-running `ionic resources` it went away.

The problem was that I had Windows-style slashes (backslashes) in the path of the icon, i.e. the error I had was this:

`Error: Source path does not exist: resources\ios\icon\icon-40.png`

So, converting backslashes into slashes resolved it for me.

**Update:**
And regarding your second error, it helped me to reset the state:

`ionic state reset`

Make sure you have `ios` listed under `cordovaPlatforms` in your `package.json` before running this command. Then `ionic` automatically re-downloads your plugins afresh and is ready to build.

Hope that helps. Take care!

Comment: It is not the answer to the question, as OP is actually missing the iPhone 6 plus icon, but it sure helped me! Easy to miss this one.

Answer (score 11):

Just use:
Remove platform

```
cordova platform remove ios
```

And add ios platform with old one

```
cordova platform add ios@4.0.0 --save
```

It worked for me..

**@4.0.0 will select previous version automatically**

Answer (score 3):

I have try some times, finally success.

1. use `ionic resources --icon` , maybe met the new problem

**"Unable to generate images due to an error Failed to upload source image: Error: read ECONNRESET"**

don't worry , try it later

2. use `ionic platform remove ios`
   when execute successfully 
   use `ionic platform add ios`

**DON'T USE`ionic state reset`**

Comment: `ionic resources --icon` made another problem
**Error: Source path does not exist: resources\ios\splash\Default~iphone.png**

Comment: Any specific reason not to use `ionic state reset` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace the "\" with "/" (backslash and slash) in the config.xml.

If you create the project on a Windows system and move to macOS for iOS compilation, it still has the Windows URI format.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this issue in several occasions and some of the provided answers worked quite well till today, when no one worked.

My environment: MacOS high Sierra 10.13, ionic cli 3.18.0 and cordova 7.1.0.

My problem was that if I run `ionic cordova prepare` it fails saying that I need to add a platform and if a I add a platform with `ionic cordova platform add ios` it fails with the error specified in the answer:

```
Error: Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png
```

What solved my issue was manually creating the platforms folder: `mkdir platforms`. After creating this folder, adding a platform worked as usual.

I hope it could help someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue with **cordova-ios@~4.5.1**

> ionic cordova build ios

```
> cordova build ios
Error: Source path does not exist: resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).
```

---

> ionic cordova platform add ios

```
> cordova platform add ios --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.1

Adding ios project...

Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:

Path: platforms/ios
Package: -
Name: -
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.4

Error: Source path does not exist: resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png
```

---

I remove ios platform

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
```

And add ios platform with old one

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@4.0.0
```

This worked for me, waiting for an **Cordova** update :)

Answer (score 1):

it's a cat and mouse problem,

1. the icon resources aren't built because the platform isn't added and
2. platform can't be added because the icon resource isn't there

ionic/cordova is pretty unstable and a nightmare to work with in CI pipeline.

this kept crashing out CI pipeline. just keep removing and adding the android/ios platform and build the resources using `ionic cordova resources --force`

Answer (score 0):

Running these commands solved it for me:

> ionic platform rm ios
>
> ionic resources
>
> ionic platform add ios

Answer (score 0):

It says that the resources directory only contained empty folders. Downloading this repo (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/tree/master/resources) 
 and replace the resources directory

Run again the "ionic cordova resources".

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually copy the files from any another project repo
such as https://github.com/sphilee/eTAS_GPS/tree/master/resources/ios

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the cordova to fix this error: to update the cordova run below command

```
$sudo npm install -g cordova@6.2.0
```

once you update the cordova type below command to remove the platform

```
$sudo ionic cordova platform rm ios --save
```

And then add platform again using below command

```
$sudo ionic cordova platform add ios --save
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem:

> Error: Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png

Looks like the relative path is in reference to the config.xml. If the resources folder exists inside of 'www', then you may need to update the relative path.

I was able to resolve this by updating the relative path to "www/resources/...".

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your resources haven't been run.

Run:

```
npm i -g cordova-ionic platform rm ios
ionic platform rm ios // You want to do this just so when you recreate you have necessary resouces
ionic cordova resources
ionic cordova build --release <ios/android>
```

There should be more answers with this solution, since ionic is a project based on npm and this command will install the necessary libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I used the no brain way, but it works. I added the ressources temporarily with the name they ask for.

Like I copy and past an image `icon-20 copy.png` then rename it into my needed ressources like `icon-small@2x.png`

Answer (score 0):

use

> **ionic cordova resources --icon**

if permission required use **sudo**

> **sudo ionic cordova resources --icon**

it will Generated 28 resources for iOS and Generated 6 resources for Android.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you add:
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0

to the widget section(on the very top) of your config.xml

This will add all necessary Cordova components.