# Why Cordova build greater then 6.3.1 cause Error: Source path does not exist: resources\ios\icon\

Tags: ios, cordova

My Cordova version using 6.3.1, when I'm adding Cordova platform add iOS, then cause error "Error: Source path does not exist: resources\ios\icon\xxx.png" error. It stop me to going forward the process. I saw solution here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615582/error-building-ios-with-cordova) but still didn't know why. Does anyone could description why cause this issue and if I don't want to downgrade Cordova version, how do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've been going a bit crazy with what I think is the same issue: updated to latest Cordova and suddenly it can't find my icons though nothing has moved.

Found a clue here: [config.xml in Cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/config_ref/index.html)

> this file can be found in the top-level directory:
>
> app/config.xml
>
> Note that before version 3.3.1-0.2.0, the file existed at app/www/config.xml, and that having it here is still supported.

I don't think it is in fact supported. I moved config.xml to the app root then changed all the paths within config.xml to point to app/www/res/iconname.png and build now works again. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'www/' before 'resources/ios/...'.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit might be in your icon itself. Right click the icon and hit Properties. Under General tab, check if the Type of file is PNG File (.png) or PNG File (.PNG).

If it was .PNG, edit your icon and save it with an extension of ".png". Viola!